# Making a Block of Text into a list

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5

I am writing a Python script that enumerates all processes running on the computer. My current code does this but prints this out in a large block of text that is hard to read. How can I improve my script to have the output text in a vertical list for each process and all?

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output('set',shell=True)
```

*Edit: Here is the output text from the above script
[image]

Comment: Give an example how your output should look like. I find that the output is already quite readable.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output` returns a string. You can do anything you want with it, for instance split it by newlines with `split`, that will create a list.

Comment: @user38034 that will split by whitespace.  maybe you meant splitlines.

Comment: @wim I meant `s.split('\n')` ;-)

Comment: That said, `splitlines` is strictly better (it doesn't end the resulting list with an empty `str` when the file happens to end with a newline, which many text editors insert automatically), and offers the option to split while keeping the newlines.

Comment: Now I notice since it is ordered, that this is mostly all program files, not really the processes currently running on the computer. Is there a way to change the script to print that, or is the output itself fine as it is? (are the list of program files the list of current running processes on the computer?)

Comment: `set` is just telling you about environment variables, not processes at all. Active process listing is completely different. At least on Win7 (not sure when it was first introduced as a built-in tool), you can use `tasklist.exe` to list running processes.

Comment: You are a lifesaver @ShadowRanger !

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Now this is an optional part of the assignment, but how can I manipulate my code to notify the user, or display when a new process is running?

Comment: You could just intermittently poll and compare the results. But if you're actually trying to monitor process creation, using a subprocess to do it is suboptimal. In your position, I'd probably get the `pywin32` extension and using [`win32process`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32process.html) functions like `EnumProcesses`, or use the more general cross-platform [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) package.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`set` should already print with newlines, so if they're not showing up, something is more wrong than you're telling us. You could always double up the newlines if you want to split the settings apart, e.g.:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output('set',shell=True).replace('\n', '\n\n'))
```

If the problem is that you're running on Python 3 and the `bytes` object is a big blob, you can make `subprocess` decode it to a friendly printable string for you:

```
print(subprocess.check_output('set',shell=True, universal_newlines=True))
# Yes, the name of the keyword is dumb; it sounds like it handles different
# line ending conventions, but on Python 3, it also decodes from `bytes`
# to `str` for you.
```

For the general case of line wrapping nicely (though it does nothing for paragraphs of text that are just "too big"), you might want to look at the [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html); it splits a block of text up into a `list` of lines wrapped nicely at word boundaries so you don't have words split across lines.

Comment: `.replace('\n', '\n\n')` is incorrect; the output shows that OP uses Python 3. `universal_newlines=True` uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` that may return something like `cp1252` while `set` may use cmd.exe OEM encoding such as `cp437`. If you don't want to use `os.environ` (that probably uses Unicode API on Windows) for some reason then you could try to [force `set` to use utf-16 encoding, to support non-ascii paths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32902728/4279)

Answer (score 0):

[`set` is an internal command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) that displays `cmd.exe` environment variables in your case.

To get environment variables in Python, use `os.environ` instead.

If you want to get the output of `set` command as a list of strings (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from subprocess import check_output

lines = check_output('cmd.exe /U /c set').decode('utf-16').split(os.linesep)
```

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I have not done what you are doing before but this might work.

```
import subprocess

processes = subprocess.check_output('set',shell=True)

processes = processes.decode('UTF-8').split('\n') # convert bytes to unicodes and split 

for process in processes:
    print(process)
```

Comment: @DylanF: it is unlikely that `set` uses utf-8 here; it is probably `cp437` i.e., expect failure if there are non-ascii paths. The output in your question clearly shows that the newline is `b'\r\n'`, not `'\n'`